# Fixing a race condition C++

Tags: c++, scheduler, race-condition

I'm working on building a rate monotonic scheduler for an assignment.  I'm     running into a racing condition with my overrun counter.  The overrun counter is supposed to say 0 for all 4 threads yet I'm constantly getting very strange numbers.  I would really appreciate some help in both identifying where the race condition is occurring and how to fix it.  Thanks in advance.

**NOTE: If it matters I'm using Cygwin for Windows to compile this program**

[image: Error]
My Scheduler.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <semaphore.h>

using namespace std;

sem_t mutex1;
sem_t mutex2;
sem_t mutex3;
sem_t mutex4;

// initialze variables
int i = 0;
int overrun1 = 0;
int overrun2 = 0;
int overrun3 = 0;
int overrun4 = 0;
int loop1 = 0;
int loop2 = 0;
int loop3 = 0;
int loop4 = 0;

bool thread1FinishFlag = false;
bool thread2FinishFlag = false;
bool thread3FinishFlag = false;
bool thread4FinishFlag = false;

pthread_attr_t mattr;
pthread_attr_t tattr;

int mainpriority = 1;
int threadpriority = 2;

int doWork();
void nsleep();
void* p1(void *param);
void* p2(void *param);
void* p3(void *param);
void* p4(void *param);


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
sem_init(&mutex1, 0, 0);
sem_init(&mutex2, 0, 0);
sem_init(&mutex3, 0, 0);
sem_init(&mutex4, 0, 0);

// initialze all threads
pthread_t thread1;
pthread_t thread2;
pthread_t thread3;
pthread_t thread4;

// actually create all threads
pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, p1, NULL);
pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, p2, NULL);
pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, p3, NULL);
pthread_create(&thread4, NULL, p4, NULL);
while (i < 160)
{

//a possible start for the race condition

    nsleep();
    if (i == 0) // initial case.  at time 0 schedule all threads
    {
        sem_post(&mutex1);
        sem_post(&mutex2);
        sem_post(&mutex3);
        sem_post(&mutex4);
    }

    else if (i % 16 == 0) // last case which happens every 16 units which schedules all threads again
    {
        if (thread1FinishFlag == false){overrun1++;}
        if (thread2FinishFlag == false){overrun2++;}
        if (thread3FinishFlag == false){overrun3++;}
        if (thread4FinishFlag == false){overrun4++;}
        sem_post(&mutex1);
        sem_post(&mutex2);
        sem_post(&mutex3);
        sem_post(&mutex4);
    }

    else if (i % 4 == 0) // case that happens every 4 units of time
    {
        if (thread1FinishFlag == false){overrun1++;}
        if (thread2FinishFlag == false){overrun2++;}
        if (thread3FinishFlag == false){overrun3++;}
        sem_post(&mutex1);
        sem_post(&mutex2);
        sem_post(&mutex3);
    }

    else if (i % 2 == 0) // case that happens every other unit of time
    {
        if (thread1FinishFlag == false){overrun1++;}
        if (thread2FinishFlag == false){overrun2++;}
        sem_post(&mutex1);
        sem_post(&mutex2);
    }

    else if (i % 1 == 0) // case that happens every unit of time
    {
        if (thread1FinishFlag == false){overrun1++;}
        sem_post(&mutex1);
    }
    i++; // increment i to go through the loop again
}

cout << "Total runs: " << i << endl;
cout << "Thread 1 overruns: " << overrun1 << endl;
cout << "Thread 2 overruns: " << overrun2 << endl;
cout << "Thread 3 overruns: " << overrun3 << endl;
cout << "Thread 4 overruns: " << overrun4 << endl;

cout << "Total thread1 runs: " << loop1 << endl;
cout << "Total thread2 runs: " << loop2 << endl;
cout << "Total thread3 runs: " << loop3 << endl;
cout << "Total thread4 runs: " << loop4 << endl;

sleep(1);
pthread_cancel(thread1);
pthread_cancel(thread2);
pthread_cancel(thread3);
pthread_cancel(thread4);
return 0;
}

// doWork function

int doWork()
{
    int lousyArray[10][10];
    int product = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            lousyArray[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < 1; k++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                product *= lousyArray[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}


//I believe the race condition begins here but I could be wrong
void* p1(void *param)
{
    thread1FinishFlag = false;
    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(&mutex1);
        thread1FinishFlag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            doWork();
        }
        loop1++;
        thread1FinishFlag = true;
    }
}

void* p2(void *param)
{
    thread2FinishFlag = false;
    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(&mutex2);
        thread2FinishFlag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            doWork();
        }
        loop2++;
        thread2FinishFlag = true;
    }
}

void* p3(void *param)
{
    thread3FinishFlag = false;
    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(&mutex3);
        thread3FinishFlag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            doWork();
        }
        loop3++;
        thread3FinishFlag = true;
    }
}

void* p4(void *param)
{
    thread4FinishFlag = false;
    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(&mutex4);
        thread4FinishFlag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            doWork();
        }
        loop4++;
        thread4FinishFlag = true;
    }
}



void nsleep()
{
    struct timespec delay;

    delay.tv_sec = 0;
    delay.tv_sec = 100000000L;
    nanosleep(&delay, NULL);
}
```

Comment: You may be interested in c++11's standard [thread support library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) as well as [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `thread[x]FinishFlag` variables are accessed and modified by multiple concurrent execution threads -- namely the main execution thread and one other execution thread, for each of these variables -- but without proper sequencing.

That's at least one obvious undefined behavior with the shown code, and is sufficient enough to result in your observed bug.

You must either use atomic variables, or introduce proper mutex locks, when accessing variables from multiple concurrent execution threads.

Implementing proper sequencing should also automatically solve a few other concurrency-related issues with the shown code.

It also wouldn't hurt to replace four copies of all variables with proper arrays/vectors. Replacing all the *foo*_1, *foo*_2, *foo*_3, and *foo*_4s with just one vector, and replacing four duplicate copies of the same thread function with a single, clean function, will result in much smaller code, and fewer opportunities to introduce more bugs.

Comment: I figured out the problem thanks to you.  In my p1, p2, p3, and p4 functions at the bottom, it was giving me weird numbers because i set the thread[x]finishflag = false twice.  I'm not sure if this is what you were referring to but I will accept your answer regardless.  Thank you so much!

Comment: The problem is more complicated than that. Even though the fixes you make appear to be sufficient enough to get your existing code working, be prepared for random problems to return when you upgrade your compiler and/or operating system. As I wrote: proper mutex locking is required for any object that's accessed by multiple concurrent execution threads.